# How to edit Chrome web (.URL) shortcuts to add 'Rating', 'Description' and 'Notes' in Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, file-management, shortcuts, bookmarks

I add web shortcuts from chrome to Windows (8.1) File Explorer (**.URL** files) into different folders so that I can access not only the downloaded documents but also the ones I want/need to check online.
But I'd like to edit their properties the same way I do with other files like .docx and .pdf (so that I can display these properties in"details view" and/or search for them). It is pretty convenient and straightforward; the properties for Chrome and Firefox shortcuts are right there just right-clicking on the shortcut, clicking properties \ Details Tab. There you'll see the properties 'Rating', 'Description' and 'Notes' which you "can" edit right there (Internet Explorer doesn't show these editable fields):

[image: Details tab]

Almost. Because when you try to apply the changes (pressing 'OK' or 'Apply' buttons), it will ask you (at least me) for Administrative privileges:

[image: File Access Denied]

...which I try to apply ('Continue' button) but:

[image: Provide Permissions]

Then I go to the specified folder to give this user (highlighted in blue in the pic) more permissions but it already has 'Full control' as you can see below. There's no way (or I can't find it) to add more permissions (like Special permission, the only one which is not ticked under 'Allow', and/so I'm not sure it would actually help.

[image: Already have Full control]

Does anyone have any idea of how could we modify these Chrome/Firefox (**.URL**) shortcut properties so that we can display and/or search for them in Windows File Explorer?

Comment: This problem also exists in Windows 10 even with updating to latest Mar-2020 update.

Comment: Is there a Microsoft uservoice for this issue? Its happened on Win10 v1607 x64 LTSB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How do I edit Chrome web shortcuts to add 'Rating', 'Description' and 'Notes'?

There is a bug which prevents you making the changes you want in the way you have described.

I've tested the workaround below with a Firefox shortcut. It should work for Chrome shortcuts as well.

---

#### Apply Property Error" occurs when attempting to modify either the Ratings, Description or Notes fields of a Favorite shortcut

> Microsoft has confirmed this to be a problem with Microsoft Windows 7 including Microsoft Windows 7 with Service Pack 1.
>
> **WORKAROUND**
>
> The issue can be alleviated by manually editing the shortcut URL in a text editor such as notepad.exe.  Simply copy and paste the desired setting i.e. Description Field, Notes fields and Ratings Field.
>
> [image]
>
> DESCRIPTION FIELD
>
> ```
> [{5CBF2787-48CF-4208-B90E-EE5E5D420294}]
>
> Prop21=31,<<< Add Description Field Text Here >>>
> ```
>
> For the Description and Notes Fields the text will need to be manually
>   edited.  The Description field outlined in Indigo in the image above. 
>   To add description text, start to the right of the comma after
>   "Prop21-31" (replacing <<< Add Description Field Text Here >>>
>   highlighted in Red in the image above with the desired text).
>
> NOTES FIELD
>
> ```
> [{B9B4B3FC-2B51-4A42-B5D8-324146AFCF25}]
>
> Prop5=31,<<< Add  Notes Field Text Here >>>
> ```
>
> Likewise, the Notes Field outlined in Green in the image above will
>   also need to be manually edited.  To add text to the Notes field,
>   start to the right of the comma after "prop5=31," (replacing <<< Add
>   Notes Field Text Here >>> highlighted in Red in the image above with
>   the desired text).
>
> For Star Ratings, all that is needed is to copy and paste the desired
>   value i.e. 1 star, 2 star, 3 star, 4 star and 5 star
>
> (Note:  a 5 star rating was copied in the sample image above).
>
> 1 Star:
>
> ```
> [{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03}]
>
> Prop9=19,1
> ```
>
> 2 Star:
>
> ```
> [{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03}]
>
> Prop9=19,25
> ```
>
> 3 Star:
>
> ```
> [{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03}]
>
> Prop9=19,50
> ```
>
> 4 Star:
>
> ```
> [{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03}]
>
> Prop9=19,75
> ```
>
> 5 Star:
>
> ```
> [{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03}]
>
> Prop9=19,99
> ```

Source ["Apply Property Error" occurs when attempting to modify either the Ratings, Description or Notes fields of a Favorite shortcut on Windows 7 with either Internet Explorer 8 or 9](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2568750)

---

#### Notes on the workaround

**Replace** the shortcut file with the **edited** file:

1. Start run "notepad"
2. Drag and drop shortcut onto notepad.
3. Make changes as required and save file.
4. Change explorer details view to show appropriate columns

Take care not to delete existing lines but just add the new ones you require.

Comment: So what you propose is to save another file together with the shortcut (or you mean to replace it?) that incorporates those properties right?  But why would we need to write that exadecimal characters? Would that allow File Explorer to display those properties on the Details View? I have tried it with the Description field in a .txt file but didn work...

Comment: @Martec You **replace** the shortcut with the edited file (right click shortcut -> edit in your favourite editor -> save over the original shortcut). Take care not to delete existing lines but just add your new ones ;). Answer updated.

Comment: Sounds nice! But right-clicking in the URL shortcuts doesn't show any 'Edit' option (nor 'open with')... (I edited the first comment before you answered it).

Comment: @martec OK (I have a right click "edit" option I forgot I added :/) . Open notepad. Drag and drop shortcut to notepad. Make and save changes. Answer updated.

Comment: Awesome, they (Microsoft) should fix the bug, as most won't use shortcuts with Details and Properties because of this,  but this workaround  might be worthy for me...

Comment: I have the 'Edit' and 'Edit with Notepad++' option for other files but for some reason not for web shortcuts...

Comment: manually editing URL file changes are not shown immediately (tested with win Vista) in explorer.exe (probably cached). I had to move URL file to another folder or change name of file to force data to refresh.

Comment: This bug is still not fixed even with Windows 10 latest Mar-2020 update.